# SSRS csv export with comma in the column header names

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-csv, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix

By default, csv takes the text box name as the csv header name for the columns. The text box does not allow a space.

How do I make a different header than the text box for the csv?
Is there a way to display comma in the header when exported to csv?

**Note**: The solution has to be only for one report; not global.

Comment: i know one very easy way .. tested ... replace space by : ALT+255

Answer (score 3):

The column name comes from the DataElementName property, or if that is blank, the Name property. Unfortunatly, neither allow commas or quoting.

There is a blog post here:

http://www.behindthecode.net/Blog/post/2008/01/29/How-to-modify-Reporting-Services-CSV-export-Behavior.aspx

on how to change settings in the config file for csv exports. These are global changes. The list of properties available is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155365.aspx

None of these allow the spaces you need, or the quoting of column names that I am currently trying to achieve. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In short, **No, it's not possible**.

From [SSRS 2008 Column issue when exporting to a CSV file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc7bcae8-cce2-4626-8cb9-132a239a4ab8/#f9bd33ae-6d92-4050-94d8-92c6e26e00cc):

> For csv export, the header of a column is determined by the `DataElementName` property of the textbox which actually contains the data. If the `DataElementName` property is not explicitly set by the user, DataElementName automatically gets defaulted to the value of the `textbox.Name` property.
>
> That being said, I believe you're getting this issue because RDL has a restriction that both a `reportItem.Name` and `reportItem.DataElementName` property must be [**CLS-compliant identifiers**](http://www.unicode.org/unicode/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html). The headings like `"Phone #"`, `"Other Name(s)"`, etc... are not CLS-Compliant.
>
> You can verify this by opening up the report in BIDS or RB and trying to set the DataElementName/Name property of the textbox containing the data to those names.
>
> You will get an error which states the following:
>
> `Property Value is not valid. Specify a valid name. The name cannot contain spaces, and it must begin with a letter followed by letters, numbers, or the underscore character (_).`

There is a Microsoft Connect Issue about this, but unfortunately it looks like it won't be acted on.
**See**: [Use of expressions for DataElementName property (for CSV Export)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/732034/)

Answer (score 1):

This solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32110072/674237

In summary:

1. Modify your query to have the first row in the data set be your desired column headers. E.g., select header names and union them to the data set.
2. Add a new CSV rendering extension to the report server that excludes headers.

This workaround will let you to put whatever values you'd like in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Append the following query parameters to your url:

- **For `#`** - *[url]*`&rs:format=CSV&rc:FieldDelimiter=%23`
- **For `;`** - *[url]*`&rs:format=CSV&rc:FieldDelimiter=";"`

Not sure you can do it directly from Report Manager without altering config files somewhere

**Update**: After rereading this, are you returning the column headers from the procedure like this?

```sql
SELECT tbl.colname [my column name, some text],  
       tbl.col2    [another, col]
```

The square brackets will allow you to escape characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It gives me a hope. In which file I have to make it? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Column names for Csv, Dbf and Xml are picked up from `<Name>` field by default.

Solved this issue by adding appropriate names for each of this formats in `<Tag>` field in *.mrt file. E.g:

`<Name>Txt_InternalName</Name>
<Tag>CSV:"Name for Csv"; DBF: "Name for DBF"; XML: "Name for Xml"; Default: "Default Name for Csv Dbf Xml"</Tag>`

Also it resolves issue with CLS non compliant identifiers in headers